# FQL: how to retrieve username/name for comment user signed in with another provider in comment social plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I just set up a nice approach to fetch comments made on my web site through FB's Comment Social Plugin, using PHP and OpenGraph/FQL requests (i'm not using Facebook SDK).

I needed it to display comments in the relative iOS app. Actually, this method retrieves all the comments, with related answers if present, and username/pic about the user who made the comment.

The problem comes with comments made by user signed with another provider. The FQL result is:

```
  "fromid": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,          //first ID, usually is uid in "user" table
  "text": "comment text", 
  "time": 1345979042, 
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",   //not relevant, URL id
        "from": {
          "name": "externaluser", 
          "id": ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ      //another ID, usually uid too, different from XXXXX 
        }, 
        "message": "test reply", 
        "created_time": 1345979528
      }
    ], 
    "count": 1
  }
```

this result correctly gives the comment text, but the IDs aren't present in the user table. The "reply" correctly return the name "externaluser", but i can't find it anywhere querying FQL tables.

I'm sure this external user is stored somewhere in Facebook DB! Can someone point me the right relationship to retrieve user's data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this FQL:

```
SELECT id, name, username FROM user WHERE third_party_id = ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

If that doesn't get you to the user, then I don't think you're going to be able to get that detail from the FB servers.

Comment: Yes, i was reading the docs and i have seen that "third_party_id", but no luck. Querying against it returns nothing. The strange thing is my above query returns TWO different ids, one for the comment ("fromid") and one for the answer ("from"->"id"). Both return nothing.. if i try them with the graph explorer it says "bad request". Mah.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue and finally found a FQL query that gives us the names of the people making comments. When pulling data from the stream, there were actually two sets of names that we needed, the names of the people posting to the stream and the names of the commenters. A triple query was needed to get the data. Its a rather large query, so I've cut it down to only the relevant fields.

```
{"q1":"SELECT source_id, likes, comments, actor_id,  post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN ( SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me())",
 "q2":"SELECT id, username, name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #q1)",
 "q3":"SELECT id,name,username FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #q1))"}
```

Query 1 gives you the items from the stream.
Query 2 gives you the information for the people that posted to the stream. You'll need to do a cross reference from actor_id in q1 to id in q1.
Query 3 gives you the information for the people that commented on anything returned in q1. You'll need to do a cross reference from formid in q1.comments.comment_list to id in q1.

Hope this helps.